# Flutter dropdown from api and stepper

Tags: flutter, dropdown, stepper

Hello am having and error when going back and forth from the stepper. The first time going to next works fine but if I press cancel and next I get error on the dropdown step. The error am getting is

native "AssertionError_throwNew";Instance of 'BookingLotsModel'.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)

The for dropdown

```
  int _currentStep = 0;
  BookingLotsModel _mySelection = BookingLotsModel(id: '0', posttitle: '');
  List<BookingLotsModel> data = [];
```

....

```
 continued() {
    print(data);
    if (_currentStep == 0) {
      APIServices.getlotsfordates(userid, _token, checking, checkout)
        .then((response) {
      setState(() {       
        data = [];
        _mySelection = BookingLotsModel(id: '', posttitle: '');
        data = bookinglotFromJson(response);
      });
     return "Sucess";
    });
    return 'null';
  }

  cancel() {
    _currentStep > 0 ? setState(() => _currentStep -= 1) : null;
  }
```

....

```
 child: DropdownButtonFormField<BookingLotsModel>(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      isDense: true,
                      hint: const Text("Select Lot"),
                      items: data.map<DropdownMenuItem<BookingLotsModel>>(
                          (BookingLotsModel value) {
                        
                        return DropdownMenuItem<BookingLotsModel>(
                          child: Text(value.posttitle),
                          value: value,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          _mySelection = newVal!;
                        });
                      },
                      value: null,
                    ),
```

BookingLotsModel

```
       List<BookingLotsModel> bookinglotFromJson(String str) =>
        List<BookingLotsModel>.from(
            json.decode(str).map((x) => BookingLotsModel.fromJson(x)));
    String bookinglotToJson(List<BookingLotsModel> data) =>
        json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
    
    class BookingLotsModel {
      String id = '';
      String? postcontent;
      String posttitle = '';

    
      BookingLotsModel(
          {required this.id,
          required this.posttitle,
});
    
      factory BookingLotsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
          BookingLotsModel(
              id: json['post']['ID'].toString(),
              posttitle: json['post']['post_title'],

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "post_title": posttitle,
            "ID": id,
          };
    }
```

Comment: Like the error says, a non-unique value was passed to the `value` for `DropdownMenuItem`, make sure the values are unique in `BookingLotsModel`, the error message will tell you the exact value that was duplicated.

Comment: the problem is the selected value. if i don't select anything the list populate and I can go back and forth.